# set umask 000 on Windows?

Tags: windows, freebsd, umask

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but don't have a lot of experience with NFS and Windows together. I have a user on a Win10 ENT box, connected up to a FreeBSD server. And with the Macs, when we get a new one, we have to set the umask to 000 for the user to be able to write and execute files they create. But we just got our first Windows box, and I can't find anything online to show the procedure to set my WIN10 ENT box to umask 000 or the Windows equivalent. Any help would be SUPER appreciated if you know.  Thanks!

Comment: Try updating the umask for `nobody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is none. In Windows, new files and folders will (by default) inherit the permissions of the directory that they are originally created in. So you should be looking at changing the ACLs on the parent directory, involving CREATOR_OWNER access rights.

Comment: That's what I thought, I just needed to hear it lol    Thanks bjoster!